# jQuery ScrollTop to Element ID not working on Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, offset, scrolltop

I need a cross-browser solution for scrolling to an element on a page. This code works perfectly on Chrome, but not Safari, nor Safari on mobile. It scrolls to the top of the page, not to the `div` id:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#div_id").offset().top - 260 }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2512) recorded on github (now closed), if you have the following code in your css:

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

, then it will prevent Safari from calculating `scrollTop` accurately (but it only affects Safari).

If you have hidden overflow css, you could remove it, or a suggested workaround (also in the post) is to use:

```
const scrollTop = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop)
```

hope this helps